# Building gtk3 apps wth golang on Gentoo

Tags: linux, compilation, gtk3, gentoo

I'm trying to build gtk3 apps with golang using Gentoo as my dev environment and Fedora 23 as my testing environment. I won't be using X on Gentoo and I might even try to target Wayland over X.

According to https://github.com/gotk3/gotk3/wiki/Installing-on-Linux

It shows the packages needed to build apps on other platforms:

UBUNTU

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```

FEDORA

```
$ sudo rpm --install gtk3-devel
$ sudo rpm --install cairo-devel
$ sudo rpm --install glib-devel
```

What are the equivalent packages on gentoo? Are they available through portage? Will I be required to install graphical dependencies like X?

Comment: The equivalent packages are `x11-libs/gtk+`, `x11-libs/cairo` and `dev-libs/glib`, respectively. `x11-libs/gtk+` indeed depends on X11 on my system (but I have the `X` USE flag set, and it looks like the ebuild can do without it, so YMMV).

Comment: This has put me on the right track... will update if I figure out how to use USE flags properly.